# TeamBuild and Web Deployment Projects

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

With the new TFS 2008 and the upcoming TFS 2010, are Web Deployment Projects depreciated?  We used them in our 2005 projects because we needed the multiple distribution of files across a cluster but now that TeamBuild does that, and we are just now moving out of VSS to TFS 2008, I was wondering if there was an argument to be made on removing the WDPs and just go with a strict TeamBuild solution.

We use CruiseControl.NET to build currently but was looking at moving to one solution instead of just using the CC.NET plugin to build from TFS Source Control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically speaking, in a team environment you want to use Web Application Projects anyway which lends itself to xcopy style deployments.  We have dozens of applications that are under active development using this method.

When using Team Build, I highly recommend you get a copy of [TFS Deployer](http://www.codeplex.com/tfsdeployer)  which enables you to utilize powershell scripts that are hooked into the Build Quality settings.

Our setup is CI (leveraging TFS 2008) with TFS Deployer.  A successful check in causes a build and deployment to our dev servers.  When we change the build quality to "In Staging" TFS Deployer moves the projects to our staging servers.  When our infrastructure team changes it to "In Production" in deploys to our web farms.

Simple, to the point

Comment: What about TFS build ability to change configuration settings based on environment like <connectionStrings/>?

Comment: Another thing, we do use Web Application Projects, but use the Web Deployment Projects for CruiseControl builds.  I am trying to raise the argument that we do not need the WDP anymore but I need some fuel for the discussion.

Comment: We maintain multiple config files for each project.  For example, web.config, web.staging.config, web.production.config.  In the TFSBuild.proj file I have code which copies the appropriate config file based on where that release is going.  Incidentally, this is pretty close to what VS2010 is going to do.

Comment: I gave up on WDP's pretty early on as they were a PITA to get going.  Once I realized that I could do everything I needed with Powershell scripts I never looked back.

Comment: I have used CruiseControl in combination with VS2005 because '05 didn't have built in CI capabilities.  It was pretty easy, but with that built into '08, we dumped it.

Comment: I'm confused about this too - with the release of VS2010 they just released a new version of the deployment tool. but getting it to work with TFS 2010 out of the box is NOT easy !! (for a newbie anyway)